# /etc/environment does not work on Solaris 10

Tags: perl, unix, ssh, environment-variables

**GOAL**: to pre-inject in Perl's @INC array on a Solaris 10 box with perl version 5.8.4, **and that this should be available in *`any`* way perl is invoked!** That includes `ssh` non-interactive logins...

So that something like:

```
ssh my.solaris.10.box 'perl -MSpecialModule -le "print qq/Powerball!\n/"'
```

Works and does not throw me attitude of `Can't locate SpecialModule.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/i86pc-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/i86pc-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/site_perl /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/i86pc-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/vendor_perl .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.`

So far I tried to add `PERLLIB=/path/to/always/include/in/INC`:

1. `/etc/environment`
2. `/etc/default/init`
3. `/etc/bash.bashrc` as `ssh my.solaris.10.box 'echo $SHELL'` gives me `SHELL=/bin/bash`
4. `~/.ssh/environment` of a specific user as in `ssh privuser@my.solaris.10.box`

Now, `/etc/profile` works, but only **if** I'm actually logged in on that box... for my purpose, I wish to execute with `ssh` non-interactively.

I'm not a SysAdmin, but I'll just share the below:

```
grep -i pam /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v '^#'
PAMAuthenticationViaKBDInt yes
```

And adding `UsePAM yes` did not do the trick.

Any other suggestion, does `/etc/default/init` require a reboot? Otherwise, `/etc/environment` works a sold for all my Linux Red Heads...

What can I do to get `/etc/environment` to work on Solaris 10?

Comment: Solaris doesn't have pluggable authentication module `pam_env.so` by default and I'm not sure if it's available as add-on. RedHat and Linux in general comes with `pam_env.so` that uses `/etc/environment` by default.

Comment: Could be, makes me think to dig more on PAM, however, the fact that `~/.ssh/environment` also does not work, makes me wonder if it might be something that hints at something simple that I don't know

Comment: Installing a wrapper for /usr/bin/perl is the typical approach. However, this has all the marking of an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Actually, in my case, I want **X** and **Y** :) Yes, to solve my INC problem per-se, the perl-wrapper (as much as I don't like it) would do the job. However, I also have other shell scripts I wish to invoke non-interactively via ssh which I'd like to take for granted that certain variables are ALWAYS set according to each specific host. It works on all my Red Hats ... only with Solaris 10 it does not

Comment: Or let's ask the question more simple and direct to ssh, why does `~/.ssh/environment` not load on Solaris 10?

Answer (score 0):

1) Note that Sun used to recommend that you install your own copy of Perl rather than mess around with what's in `/usr/perl5`.

2) Rename the `perl` binary to something else, and in its place put a tiny shell script that sets the environment the way you want it and then `exec`s the renamed binary.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this Perl was original or manually installed, what diff is it to the issue posted ?